# How to adjust 100% browser height and width with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I wanted to fit my site to browser i tried this and when i try the " width=100%
height=100% " for body's css it does ok and when i tried that with container's div it sort of disappears meaning the background color is not seen

This is html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled</title>
<link href="css/stylesheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico" /></head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
<div class="logo">
<div id="logo">Logo</span></div>
</div><!--Logo-->
<div class="search-bar">Search BAr</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is CSS

```
body{
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin: 0;
background:#CCC;
}
#container{
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin:0 auto;
background:#000;
}
#header{
width:100%;
 height:12%;
float:left;
background:#F00;
}
.logo{
width:50%;
height:100%;
float:left;
background:#0F0;
}
.search-bar{
width:50%;
height:100%;
float:left;
color:#FFF;
font-family: 'century gothic';
text-align:center;
margin-top:20px;
}
#logo
{
width:100%;
height:100%; 
float:left;
font-size:48px; 
color:#FFF;
font-family: 'century gothic';
text-align:center;
margin-top:20px;
}
```

I am in trouble help me plzzz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to apply `height` in % the parent element should have height set explicitly.

So if you simply set `height` property, the parent tag `html` doesn't have any height set so it'll take 0 height.

*Update: [Solved Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/3F3T5/3/)*

Comment: can you give example ?

Comment: @Radioactive check this http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/3F3T5/ note that i have given height for html, body and container.. if you remove any height property, the child elements inside it having height in `%` won't have any height..

Comment: What should i change in it ?    
body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
    background:#CCC;
    }
    #container{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:#000;
    }

Comment: @Radioactive you need to set height for `html` element, which is the parent of `body`.. check this http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/3F3T5/3/

Comment: please clarify one more thing i gave body's width and height 100% each and did same for container is well then what was the problem ?

Comment: problem is that you haven't set the height for `html` which is the parent of `body`.. like i mentioned in answer, if the parent element doesn't have height set explicitly the child can't have height in `%`.. so `body` will have 0 height..

Comment: I tried that but it shows scroll bars on bottom an left for width and height respectively but doesnt fit the browser check this: http://jsfiddle.net/Xz2cg/

Comment: @Radioactive that's because the browser automatically apply some css. adding `*{margin:0; padding:0}` will fix the issue. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/Xz2cg/2/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match it to the browser you could best use this.

CSS

```
body {
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
}
```

the vh, and vw represent percentage according to viewport width/height;

Comment: Bear in mind that [vw and vh aren't supported in IE8 or below](http://caniuse.com/#search=vw), if you need to support it

Answer (score 0):

If you want the size of an element to be the size of the browser then it has to be a direct child of the body and you need to add this style to the body:

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: No, the head is a direct sibling of the body, I think you mean child.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link when you set width and height

```
div{width:auto;height:auto;}
```

it will set automatically
see this link

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_width&preval=auto